# How to embed a .exe file as a resource within another .exe file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, adb, exe

I am trying to create an executable file for this program that I am writing, where it would be a standalone program that would not require python for it to work. In the program, I use the Android Debug Bridge (adb.exe). So I have this line of code in my script:

```
ver = subprocess.call(r"C:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell getprop ro.build.version.release")
```

I tried using pyinstaller and py2exe to make my script into an executable file, however, those fail to create a successful executable file where the adb runs properly.

So my question is, how would I be able to incorporate a .exe file within another .exe file?

Comment: maybe can try [Adding Binary Files](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle), I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: and don't forget the `Adb*.dll`

Comment: Thank you! I will try that :)

Answer (score -1):

so subprocess.run takes("the excutable","task")
like

subprocess.run("7zip.exe","unzip")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).